# SwiftUI Picker: the selection "nil" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a picker view in a SwiftUI view using @Query as the data source.

Not sure what I am missing? Do I need to have an id in my model?

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
@Query var customers: [Customer]
@State private var selectedCustomer: Customer?

Section {
    Picker("", selection: $selectedCustomer) {
Text("SelectCustomer").tag(Optional<String>(nil))

        ForEach("", id: \.self){ customer in 
              Text(customer.clientName).tag(customer as Customer?)
        }
    }
}

import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Customer {
    var dateCreated: Date
    var clientName: String
    var clientEmail: String
    var streetAddress: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
    var zipCode: String
    var contactPerson: String
    var contactEmail: String
    var phone: String
    var notes: String
}
// init ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
Text("SelectCustomer").tag(nil as Customer?)
```

and

```
ForEach(customers, id: \.self){ customer in  ....
```

If you add an `id` and `Identifiable` to your `Customer` model, then you can use

```
 ForEach(customers){ customer in  ....
```

Your error is from `Text("SelectCustomer").tag(Optional<String>(nil))`.

The tag of each element of the `Picker` must match the `selectedCustomer: Customer?`.
So you can see that `Optional<String>` is not of type `Customer?`.
If you really have to, you can also have

```
 Text("SelectCustomer").tag(Optional<Customer>(nil))
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. So I guess that picker has to have a default value?